# GraphQL - Variable id cannot be non input type Float

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

Probably a absolute beginner question:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";

export const productQuery = gql`
    query Product($id: Float!){
        getProduct(id:$id){
            name,
            description,
            variants{price}
        }
    }
`;

export default graphql(productQuery, {
  options: props => ({ variables: { "id": 1 } })
});
```

I get this error message back in my developer console:

```
"GraphQL error: Variable '$id' cannot be non input type 'Float!'. (line 1, column 20):
query Product($id: Float!) {
                   ^
GraphQL error: Unknown type 'Float'. (line 1, column 20):
query Product($id: Float!) {
                   ^
GraphQL error: Cannot query field 'getProduct' on type 'Query'. (line 2, column 3):
  getProduct(id: $id) {
  ^"
```

I have no problem with this query, if I send it with the graphQLi tool. 
What could be wrong?

Comment: That second error message is particularly perplexing. Is this a Go backend? If so, I've [seen that before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916845).

Comment: It‘s typescript/node
I changed $id to $recordId without any effect :-/

Comment: Is this the only query that's giving you problems, or are you not able to query the server from the react app period? Can you share your client configuration?